# Indefinite integral of 1/(L-x) dx in sympy python

Tags: python, sympy, calculation, integral, indefinite

I tried to calculate the indefinite integral of `1/(L-x)dx` in sympy:

```
from sympy import *
x, L = symbols('x L')
f = 1/(L-x)
integrate(f, x)
```

it returned:

> -log(-L + x)

while it should be:

> -log(L-x)

Is it related to sympy or I missed something, thanks for any explanation.

I have not found an answer for this paricular function.

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate both with respect to `x`, you'll find the same result. You can check with Wolframalpha.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/derivative-calculator

As far as I understand you haven't provided constraints on L, so it can be  positive or negative which I assume is the origin of your confusion. Regardless both formulae yield what you want.

Comment: The Python result is equal to that of the Wolfram alpha integrator for negative values of L, but the results are not the same for positive values.

Comment: That is why, when you compute integrals you provide constraints. Both solutions are valid, it just depends on what you assume.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you why that happens right now.

However, this is a simple function to integrate, so we can asks sympy to mimic integration by hands with the option `manual=True`:

```py
f.integrate(x, manual=True)
# out: -log(L-x)
```

which is the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Indefinite integrals are defined only up to an additive constant. The difference between `log(x - L)` and `log(L - x)` is `I*pi` which is a constant.

Considering that you might only be interested in real-valued expressions you might prefer one or the other form but which one `integrate` should return in that case is still ambiguous: the two expressions differ in that one gives real values for `x > L` and the other gives real values for `x < L`.